# Drawing with two CALayers on top of each other

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, calayer

I have 2 views and I want to use their respective layers for drawing. My first view, which I'll call the `TextView`, is nothing but a page full of text. The other view, which I'll call `DrawView`, is where the drawing happens. In `TextView`, the layer is used to draw the text of the PDF into the view. For example:

[image: View showing contents of PDF]

The DrawView's layer on the other hand is where the custom drawing is being made. (e.g. freeform drawings, rectangles, etc.)

Now what I want to happen is to have the drawings in the `DrawView` appear as if they are being drawn *under* the `TextView`. Like this:

[image: Highlighted text]

What I did was to add DrawView as a subview of TextView. But this is what happened:

[image: text covered with color]

I tried using the `kCGBlendModeMultiply` like what was used in the second image, but nothing happens. Can anyone tell on how to make this work? Thanks.

**NOTE:** The only reason that the second image achieved what I want is because I inserted the rectangle inside the same layer, which is the TextView's layer. I want to do the same effect but inside the DrawView layer, which is a subview of the TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea:

You can use 3 layers, instead of 2. The highlighted region can be on layer 1 (the back layer). The text document can be on layer 2 (middle) and the drawing layer can be on layer 3 (the front layer).

Set the opacity of layer 3 to some intermediate value, so that you can still see what's on layer 2.

When the user draws, have layer 3 be the view that actually accepts the drawing. Since it is semi-transparent, you will still be able to see the middle layer. When the touchesEnded is called, copy the drawing onto layer 1, where it can stay. remove it from layer 3, and you should accomplish what you want.

Is that what you were thinking?

Comment: Yes that's what I was thinking. I'll try your suggestion and see if it will work. Thanks!

Comment: great! Not sure what kind of performance hit this will cause. If you're doing it on an iPad, copying an entire view can be very expensive. You can try disabling the opacity if you have memory issues, since that helps significantly.

Comment: I'm sorry but how do I set the CALayer as transparent? I only did this: `self.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;`. Is that correct?

Comment: that sets the background color to be clear, but I think you should be able to set the .alpha property to something like 0.5 (0=clear, 1=opaque) and then the whole layer would be transparent

Comment: Hey I want to ask additional question. In my `TextView` I'm using its own layer to display the text of the PDF. If I created another layer inside it like this: `CALayer *drawLayer = [CALayer layer]; drawLayer.frame = self.frame; [self.layer addSubLayer:drawLayer];`, how will I call the `drawLayer:inContext:` of drawLayer?

Comment: not sure exactly. To be honest I haven't done much with CALayer. You're best to ask a new question and consider marking this if my conceptual answer helped you! Cheers